# is register_next_step_handler exist in aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

we have something like:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def process_start(message):
    text = 'start'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_mid)


def process_mid(message):
    text = 'mid'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_end)


def process_end(message):
    text = 'end'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

in pyTelegramBotAPI
this function is for when you ask user for like a number and after he/she sends num you process it in that special func that you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

evgfilim1:
Hello. You need to use FSM, it's more flexible than register_next_step_handler.
Check the example: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

The linked page won't break as the implementation is not going to change in aiogram 2.x.